# Preparing the data for the time-series forecasting

Tags: python, time-series, preprocessor

Having a data as below: that is prepared for a real problem.

[image: Dataset]

- **Month:** There are 12 month from January to December
- **Week :** Represents the week of the month 1,2,3,and 4
- **Day  :** Day of the week from Monday to Sunday.
- **Date :** The date of that sample
- **Year :** The year
- **Regular Day?:** Representing the type of the day; regular, national holiday, and religious holiday
- **Hour :** The hour of the day from 0 to 23.
- **Temreat :** Temperature of that period.
- **DE :** Target variable.

Planing to apply first simple machine learning model such as MLP, then more complex model such as LSTM. However, before using any of that models, I know that I have to prepare the dataset. For that part, I am little bit confused for some features. Here is what I am planing to do for each features.

- **Month:** Use one-hot encoding, such as January will be `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]` and February will be `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]` etc.
- **Week :** Leave as it is.
- **Day  :** Use one-hot encoding, such as Monday will be `[0 0 0 0 0 0 1]` and Tuesday will be `[0 0 0 0 0 1 0]` etc.
- **Date :** Remove it
- **Year :** Remove it
- **Regular Day?:** Use one-hot encoding, such as regular will be `[0 0 1]`, national holiday will be`[0 1 0]` etc.
- **Hour :** Leave as it is
- **Temreat :** Leave as it is

Still I have some doubt, and I am not sure whether I am following the correct way.

Can anyone confirm, fix, or recommend for the what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say there is only one valid way to approach such problem. Your approach seems valid (at least to me).

A couple of notes:

- Make sure your validation set occurs after your train set, and make sure your test set occurs after your validation set. Such problems don't follow the same approach as traditional problems where time might not be a constraint.
- For days of the week, I would recommend using something more analog than one-hot encoding. For example, instead of representing a Monday as `[0 0 0 0 0 0 1]`, you'll represent it as `[0.5 0.1 0 0 0.1 0.5 1]` (choose the weights you want). This might help your model relate Monday to Sunday and Tuesday. Not sure if this method has a name. You can do the same for hours and months as well.
- If you can, write tests for your preparation code; it's easy to miss/mess something with python, and if you write tests in advance, it will help you down the road. For me, I've done this mistake countless times, where I don't write tests and I end up missing something and the models end up behaving way differently when fixing the issue. Make sure you write tests/checks for any assumption you have about the data as well.
- Visualize/Plot features/results when you can, this helps you a lot in innovating with your features, discovering problems, and explaining the model.
- Don't jump to training right away. Although it can be the most productive and fun phase, you can easily slip on a thing or two along the way. Cleaning the data, exploring it, feature engineering, and automating all that (if you're repeating it) is as essential as training.